# neo4j performance of adding new nodes and relations

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, relationship

My neo4j graph is pretty simple : it consists of Users and "Follows" relaionships between them. There is index for User label on "login" property. Here is the fragment of the graph:

```
{
            "nodes": [
              {
                "id": "3216",
                "labels": [
                  "User"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "login": "user#111",
                  "status": 16
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "3218",
                "labels": [
                  "User"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "login": "user#1983",
                  "status": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "relationships": [
              {
                "id": "4188",
                "type": "Follows",
                "startNode": "3216",
                "endNode": "3218",
                "properties": {}
              }
            ]
          }
}
```

status field of User node indicates whether it was handled - all the relationships are created.
Then I have the node.js app that is performing the following steps:

1. Selects the next node that has status = 1(unhandled)
2. Obtains the login of the node that was selected on step 1.
3. Requests the web service for the followers of the user with login selected on step 2.
4. Adds the new User nodes and "Follows" relationships by using cypher statements that take care of uniqueness of nodes and relaionships, REST API and cypher transactions end-point, here is the sample of the query:

```js
function buildQuery(login, followers){
  return {
    statement : 'MATCH (me:User {login : {login} }) FOREACH (f IN {followers} | MERGE (u:User { login : f }) MERGE u-[:Follows]->me),  
    parameters : {
      login : login,
      followers : followers
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment the DB has 350K User nodes and and 1.9M relationships and adding the new ones is **TERRIBLY** slow. It takes about ~8 seconds to add the single follower and the corresponding relationship on a quite powerful machine(8 core CPU, 14 GB RAM) which does not do anything else - it's Ubuntu server hosted on Azure specifically for Neo4 DB.

I am wondering is there anything I can do in order to improve the performance of addigng the new nodes? Tuning the query? Tuning the Neo4j configuration? Using Core Java API? Something else? Thanks!

Comment: Can you run your statement with some sample data but prefixed with PROFILE in the Neo4j browser and share the PROFILE output?

Comment: Yes, I run the following query: PROFILE MATCH (me:User {login : "hbo"} ) 
UNWIND ["hbo2", "hbo3", "hbo4", "hbo21", "hbo24", "hbo20", "hbo12", "hbo32", "hbo52", "hbo92", "hbo27", "hbo29", "hbo22", "hbo42"] as f  
MERGE (u:User { login : f })
MERGE (u)-[:Follows]->(me) and here is the result saved as Json : https://gist.github.com/sAbakumoff/60d16e09ce3448b53bd8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement should take a few ms at most.

Do you have a constraint on `:User(login)` ?

`create constraint on (u:User) assert u.login is unique`

Do you use 2.3.1 ?

Please both and report back.

If you can't upgrade to 2.3.1 for any reason let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! I am using v2.3.1 for sure, bit I didn't introduce any constraints on :User(login). Could you elaborate more on this? How does it affect the query performance?

Comment: Update : I added the constraint and started the app from scratch by using the fresh DB. So, 24 hrs of app's run produced ~550K nodes and ~4M relationships between them. I guess that this is the best result I can expect..Thank for the tip anyway.

Comment: A constraint on :User(login) will allow neo4j to use a unique index when finding your users to connect, which is way faster than scanning the whole db for the user.

Comment: by the way : the app I used neo4j is http://github6.azurewebsites.net, basically it makes the snapshot of github users social graph and let users to view the shortest paths between each other

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your statement to this:

```
MATCH (me:User {login : {login} }) 
UNWIND {followers} as f  
MERGE (u:User { login : f })
MERGE (u)-[:Follows]->(me)
```

Sometimes MERGE within FOREACH didn't use the unique index.